# Kernel panic: kernel_task

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, kernel-panic

my Mac goes in kernel panic for reasons unknown to me, log from diagnostic report:

```
Anonymous UUID:       C144D1C9-52C0-9A38-FC07-61FEF6C5BDAB

Mon Jun 13 13:00:38 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff80031ce5fa): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f8559cf76, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff80e8da9004, CR3: 0x000000000636a000, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0
RAX: 0x0000000050c6c021, RBX: 0xffffff801c215d00, RCX: 0x0000000000040004, RDX: 0x0000000000000003
RSP: 0xffffff810e313d28, RBP: 0xffffff810e313d30, RSI: 0x0000000000040004, RDI: 0xffffff801597b000
R8:  0xffffff801bf75400, R9:  0xffffff801749ac00, R10: 0x00000000fffffffc, R11: 0xffffff80e8d69000
R12: 0xffffff7f855ea080, R13: 0xffffff801bf75400, R14: 0xffffff8016fe8a00, R15: 0x0000000010001000
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff7f8559cf76, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff80e8da9004, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x3, PL: 0

Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff810e3139b0 : 0xffffff80030dab12 
0xffffff810e313a30 : 0xffffff80031ce5fa 
0xffffff810e313c10 : 0xffffff80031ec463 
0xffffff810e313c30 : 0xffffff7f8559cf76 
0xffffff810e313d30 : 0xffffff7f8558b07e 
0xffffff810e313d40 : 0xffffff7f8558c020 
0xffffff810e313d90 : 0xffffff7f8553571c 
0xffffff810e313db0 : 0xffffff7f85535631 
0xffffff810e313dd0 : 0xffffff7f85589209 
0xffffff810e313df0 : 0xffffff7f855910f0 
0xffffff810e313e10 : 0xffffff7f85517393 
0xffffff810e313e40 : 0xffffff7f855191cb 
0xffffff810e313e60 : 0xffffff7f85517f58 
0xffffff810e313e90 : 0xffffff8003690598 
0xffffff810e313ed0 : 0xffffff80036b353e 
0xffffff810e313f10 : 0xffffff800368f6f4 
0xffffff810e313f90 : 0xffffff800368f977 
0xffffff810e313fb0 : 0xffffff80031c9017 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(205.10)[949D9C27-0635-3EE4-B836-373871BC6247]@0xffffff7f85503000->0xffffff7f8556efff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D8216D61-5209-3B0C-866D-7D8B3C5F33FF]@0xffffff7f839f4000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[172C2960-EDF5-382D-80A5-C13E97D74880]@0xffffff7f844b7000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics(10.1.4)[E5BC31AC-4714-3A57-9CDC-3FF346D811C5]@0xffffff7f8557d000->0xffffff7f855eafff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(108.2.1)[B5ADE17A-36A5-3231-B066-7242441F7638]@0xffffff7f84380000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D8216D61-5209-3B0C-866D-7D8B3C5F33FF]@0xffffff7f839f4000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[172C2960-EDF5-382D-80A5-C13E97D74880]@0xffffff7f844b7000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(205.10)[949D9C27-0635-3EE4-B836-373871BC6247]@0xffffff7f85503000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
15F34

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.5.0: Tue Apr 19 18:36:36 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.50.21~8/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7E7B0822-D2DE-3B39-A7A5-77B40A668BC6
Kernel slide:     0x0000000002e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8003000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8002f00000
System model name: MacBookPro11,1 (Mac-189A3D4F975D5FFC)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 14456962487644
last loaded kext at 13185505161296: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f85c0d000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 13305030027623: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc  5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f85c0d000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
foo.tap 1.0
foo.tun 1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.0.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.0.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.0.12
com.zerotier.tap    1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.0.12
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.22.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.6.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.5f3
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.46.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1040.1.1a6
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.9
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.9
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.9
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   2.0.60
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.10
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 2.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.4
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
```

can someone advise what to do?

What I did: I ran the test (hold D when mackbook start and that test told me everything is fine)

**Config:** MacBook pro 13" retina mid-2014

**UPD:** I noticed that the Mac dies when connecting charging

**UPD:** [Another log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f9187f1fcf8c93d5be96b1fa6c76a634) after crash

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed all available OS X updates?

Try booting up in recovery mode (hold Cmd-Option-R during boot). Does the system crash in recovery mode too?

Have you tried reinstalling OS X - does it help?

If you have got a working system on a USB drive or perhaps a Live-DVD, try booting that to see if it crashes there.

If you see crashes with a different set of software, it all points to a hardware error.

Considering your backtrace it could be due to for example an overheating CPU (i.e. defective cooling) or an RAM error. If you have spare RAM lying around, you could try swapping it out.